# Razor View find Id assigned in loop from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, for-loop

I have the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Questions.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.TextAreaFor(modelItem => Model.Questions[i].AnswerText, new { @class = "form-control multi", rows = "6" })
    <div class="remaining-counter">
        <p><span id="Counter_@i"></span> characters remaining</p>
    </div>
}
```

I am trying to implement a remaining counter for each text area using jquery simply countable

```
$('.multi').simplyCountable({
    counter: 'How to get the id here',
    countType: 'characters',
    maxCount: 4000,
    strictMax: false,
    countDirection: 'down',
    thousandSeparator: ',',
});
```

What I cant figure out is how to get the appropriate id for the counter span that shows the remaining count `<span id="Counter_@i"></span>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but I feel hacking the plugin to hard-wire a selector is a terrible solution.

### Two options...

**Option 1 - no plugin change required**

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/e82kf82r/7/

You can iterate the `.multi` elements and wire them up individually with the matching span IDs like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('.multi').each(function () {
        var counter = $(this);
        counter.simplyCountable({
            counter: '#' + counter.next().find("span").attr('id'),
            countType: 'characters',
            maxCount: 4000,
            strictMax: false,
            countDirection: 'down',
            thousandSeparator: ',',
        });
    });
});
```

**Option 2 - improve the plugin**

A nicer solution would be to improve the plugin so that the `counter` option is used to find elements relative to the element plugged in. This will require a common ancestor element so that the `textarea` and counter can be located.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/e82kf82r/9/

```
$(function () {
    $('.container').simplyCountable({
        counter: 'span',
        countType: 'characters',
        maxCount: 4000,
        strictMax: false,
        countDirection: 'down',
        thousandSeparator: ',',
    });
});
```

HTML change (added parent divs):

```
<div class="container">
    <textarea class="multi"></textarea>
    <div class="remaining-counter">
        <p><span class="safe">3,979</span> characters remaining</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Extract of changes to plugin:

The default options add a `text` selector:

```
$.fn.simplyCountable = function (options) {
    options = $.extend({
        text: 'textarea',
        counter: '.counter',
```

The new plugin initialising code looks like:

```
return $(this).each(function () {
        var $element = $(this);
        var countable = $element.find(options.text);
        var counter = $element.find(options.counter);
```

Answer (score 1):

i don't know if its correct way but you can replace this line in jquery.simplyCountable.js file:-

```
var counter = $(options.counter);

with 

var counter = $(this).next().find('span');
```

[Updated js file](http://jsfiddle.net/e82kf82r/3/)

or you can simply do this:-

```
$(function () {
        $('.multi').each(function () {
            var id = $(this).next().find('span').attr('id');
            $(this).simplyCountable({
                counter: '#' + id,
                countType: 'characters',
                maxCount: 4000,
                strictMax: false,
                countDirection: 'down',
                thousandSeparator: ',',
            });
        });

    });
```

Comment: Hacking the plugin with a custom selector is a really bad idea. Either attaching `simplyCountable` to each element separately, or *improving* the plugin are better options. I have provide examples of both. Note: *you have duplicate span `id`s in your sample making the HTML invalid*

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie duplicate `ids` in sample is just copy paste div for sample in real code `ids` generating dynamic using for loop as you can see in question

Comment: That was just a suggestion to correct your JSFiddle. Feel free to ignore it.